How to vertically align the \Downarrow in equation?
I have consulted some answers in TSE, but I didn't found satisfactory solution to solve my case in typeset \Downarrow.
Here below is my MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixdif}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \d x &= W_1 \frac{\d V + C \d t}{V} + W_2 \frac{\d Y C_Y \d t}{Y} + W_3r \d t\\
        &= [W_1(\alpha-r) + W_2(\alpha_Y-r)]\d t + [W_1\sigma + W_2\sigma_Y] \d z\\
        & \qquad \qquad \qquad \Downarrow\text{XXX} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \, \, \,\Downarrow\text{YYY} \\
        &\quad  W_1(\alpha-r) + W_2(\alpha_Y-r) = 0 \quad \enspace W_1\sigma+W_2\sigma_Y = 0  
\end{align*}
\end{document}


And My ideal result's requirement in the figure:

The begin of \Downarrow start from the "+" with RED symbol;
The end of the \Downarrow points to the middle(or the north) of two blue equation boxes
Is there convenient methods to adjust the length of \Downarrow?

The Extraordinary solution result by egreg as below:(elegant align and scale the \DownArrow)


Sorry, but there's no way to typeset elegantly the formulas: they will overlap.
The following command has an optional argument (default \mathbin, use \conseq[\mathrel]{...}{...} if you want to adorn a relation symbol).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normal]{fixdif}

\newcommand{\conseq}[4][\mathbin]{%
  #1{%
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    #2 \\ % operation or relation
    \hidewidth {}\mathbin{\Big\Downarrow\makebox[0pt][l]{ #3}}{} \hidewidth \\
    \hidewidth \displaystyle #4\hidewidth
    \end{array}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \d x
  &= W_1 \frac{\d V + C \d t}{V} + W_2 \frac{\d Y C_Y \d t}{Y} + W_3r \d t\\
  &= [W_1(\alpha-r) 
     \conseq{+}{XXX}{W_1(\alpha-r) + W_2(\alpha_Y-r) = 0}
     W_2(\alpha_Y-r)]\d t 
    \conseq{+}{YYY}{W_1\sigma+W_2\sigma_Y = 0}
    [W_1\sigma + W_2\sigma_Y] \d z
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \d x
  &= W_1 \frac{\d V + C \d t}{V} + W_2 \frac{\d Y C_Y \d t}{Y} + W_3r \d t\\
  &= [W_1(\alpha-r) 
     \conseq{+}{XXX}{W_1(\alpha-r) + W_2(\alpha_Y-r) = 0}
     W_2(\alpha_Y-r)]\d t 
    %\conseq{+}{YYY}{W_1\sigma+W_2\sigma_Y = 0}
    +
    [W_1\sigma + W_2\sigma_Y] \d z
\end{align*}

\end{document}

The second display shows that the command does what you want.

If you accept stagggered equations:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normal]{fixdif}

\NewDocumentCommand{\conseq}{O{\mathbin}mO{\Big}mm}{%
  #1{%
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    #2 \\ % operation or relation
    \hidewidth {}\mathbin{#3\Downarrow\makebox[0pt][l]{ #4}}{} \hidewidth \\
    \hidewidth \displaystyle #5\hidewidth
    \end{array}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \d x
  &= W_1 \frac{\d V + C \d t}{V} + W_2 \frac{\d Y C_Y \d t}{Y} + W_3r \d t\\
  &= [W_1(\alpha-r) 
     \conseq{+}[\big]{XXX}{W_1(\alpha-r) + W_2(\alpha_Y-r) = 0}
     W_2(\alpha_Y-r)]\d t 
    \conseq{+}[\Bigg]{YYY}{W_1\sigma+W_2\sigma_Y = 0}
    [W_1\sigma + W_2\sigma_Y] \d z
\end{align*}

\end{document}



Oh, the overlap due to my failure contruction of my MWE, but the method to align is useful!

A little not so correct as my original problem is that the second start point of '+' is the last one between W_1\sigma + W_2\sigma_Y, and your brilliant command conseq is elegant! thank u very much!

with my test to align it with the correct '+' it didn't overlap, shown appended the original question, thanks egreg!
